# SpringMVC restful style URL with optional parameter

Tags: spring-mvc

Now I need pass some unsure quantity of parameter to a controller in restful, and I'm doing <del>everything well</del> as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/list/{mcategory}/{scategory}/{pageNumber}.html",
                       "/list/{mcategory}.html",
                       "/list/{mcategory}/{pageNumber}.html")
public ModelAndView list(@PathVariable String mcategory, @PathVariable String scategory, @PathVariable Integer pageNumber)
```

but as you can see, those bloody mappings are too heavy to read and understand, I'm wondering if there is a better salutation?

**update**

I'm quite sorry, at beginning I mentioned that "I'm doing everything well", previously I didn't see the mapping exception, so I thought everything is okay, but while I tested those mappings, it throws

```
"Mapped "{[/info/list/{mcategory}/{scategory}/{pageNumber}.html || /info/list/{mcategory}.html || /info/list/{mcategory}/{pageNumber}.html],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.asc.modules.InformationModule.list(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException"
```

appreciate.

Comment: optional `PathVariable` seems not possible with annotation. i will suggest extracting the method and use 3 `RequestMapping`, or process the `HttpServletRequest` manually

Comment: I can't see any exception in your post. It's a quite normal log output. Maybe you should consult the spring docs a bit more?

Comment: @hsluo yes, that's what I'm doing now, and I searched a lot, seems there isn't any other solution except what you mentioned

Comment: @DirkLachowski there is exception at the end of code 2, "..throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException"

Comment: @DirkLachowski and if you put all those annotation mappings together like I post above, only first request url will be mapped properly, all others will return 404

Comment: @Z.Nesson Nope, it's an information that the controllers method *can* throw the named exception. If there is an exception thrown then show the full stack trace.

Comment: @DirkLachowski hmm... I see, it indeed an information during springMVC  starting up, but the description is really confused like that.